# Why is the props not passed to my Component in this beginner question

Tags: reactjs

Beginner question!
As you see on the image the `ratio`, `background` all 4 have values in them but when I
pass them to `Itemrender` like this:

```
<Component aaa={(ratio, background, fileData, id, week)} />
```

And when `ItemRenderer` receive them the aaa is only "1"

[image]

Here is `Itemrender` and the `aaa` = "1"

[image]

Comment: Please include relevant code as formatted text, not as pictures of code.  To learn more, you are encouraged to read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the value for `week` is `"1"`?  This syntax looks wrong to me:

```
aaa={(ratio, background, fileData, id, week)}
```

It looks like it's effectively just passing the last value.  If you want to pass them all as an object, use the object literal `{}` syntax:

```
aaa={{ratio, background, fileData, id, week}}
```

Comment: @ExocetKid: For both of us.  I had to test my theory first, because I've honestly never used that syntax of wrapping items in parentheses (outside of invoking a function of course) and wasn't sure how/why it worked at all.  I'm sure there's a name and use for it, but not one I'm familiar with :)

Comment: Is there another way to do this then  (outside of invoking a function of course)?  I learn this and would like to info